# Is it possible for malware to overwrite UEFI code when installing an operating system?

Tags: operating-systems, uefi, secure-boot

If the ISO file for an operating system is malicious, is it possible for it to overwrite UEFI code when booted (If secure boot is disabled)?

Comment: Unless the firmware itself enforces security like signed firmware updates any process with root/administrator permissions should be able to modify UEFI firmware. That is not limited to the OS installation phase. So yes, that should be possible.